# How to determine the number of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let's say we have the following items:

$A_1$

$B_1, B_2, B_3$

$C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$

$D_1, D_2$

$E_1$

$F_1, F_2$

How many combinations of four items can we make when there can only be zero or one items of each letter?

Comment: Are objects corresponding to each letter, for example, $B_1,B_2,B_3$ different from each other or identical?

Comment: @AnuragA all items are different from each other, so A1-B1-C1-D1 is a different combination than A1-B2-C1-D1.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.    When you pose a question on this site, you should show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering. This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something we'll have to do a little bit "by hand".

What we'll do is enumerate various ways of getting four letters out of `ABCDEF` and then figure out how many ways we can get those four letters given varying numbers of each type of object.  There are $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ ways to get four letters:

`ABCD: 1*3*4*2 = 24 ways
ABCE: 1*3*4*1 = 12
ABCF: 1*3*4*2 = 24
ABDE: 1*3*2*1 =  6
ABDF: 1*3*2*2 = 12
ABEF: 1*3*1*2 =  6
ACDE: 1*4*2*1 =  8
ACDF: 1*4*2*2 = 16
ACEF: 1*4*1*2 =  8
ADEF: 1*2*1*2 =  4
BCDE: 3*4*2*1 = 24
BCDF: 3*4*2*2 = 48
BCEF: 3*4*1*2 = 24
BDEF: 3*2*1*2 = 12
CDEF: 4*2*1*2 = 16`

Add all these up and we get $244$ distinct ways to select four objects so that each is from a different category.  This is out of $\binom{13}{4} = 715$ ways to select four objects without this restriction.